# I didn't get the correct value of title to pass

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is my java file I didn't get the correct value of title to pass to localweb
send value through this line

> .appendQueryParameter("Title",textviewtitle.setText(title);)

what parameter I use to send correct value instead of above line, this file get intent data from another activity but in textview it show correct title and didn't send correct value as parameter

fullview.java

```
package com.desktop.app;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.*;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_AUTHOR;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_HR;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_PUBLISHER;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_PUBY;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_RAK;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_STATUS;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_TITLE;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_VR;

public class fullview extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button location, avail, request;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullview);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String title = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
        String author = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_AUTHOR);
        String publisher = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PUBLISHER);
        int  puby = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_PUBY,0);
         final int  rak = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_RAK,0);
         final int  hr = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_HR,0);
         final int  vr = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_VR,0);
        final String status = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_STATUS);

        TextView textviewtitle = findViewById(R.id.textviewtitle);
        TextView textViewAuthor = findViewById(R.id.textviewauthors);
        TextView textViewPublisher = findViewById(R.id.textviewpublisher);
        TextView textViewPuby = findViewById(R.id.textviewpubyear);

        textviewtitle.setText(title);
        textViewAuthor.setText(author);
        textViewPublisher.setText(publisher);
        textViewPuby.setText(String.valueOf(puby));

        location = findViewById(R.id.loc);
        location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(fullview.this);
//                a_builder.setMessage("Location");
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(fullview.this);

                    builder.setTitle("Location");
                    builder.setMessage("Rak-No :: " + rak +  "\nColumn :: " + hr +"\nRow :: " + vr);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog=null;

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(fullview.this,"Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });//.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//
//                        }
//                    });
                    alertDialog=builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            }
        });

        avail = findViewById(R.id.avail);
        avail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(fullview.this);
                    {
                        if (status.equals("yes")) {
                            builder.setTitle("Availablity");
                            builder.setMessage("Available");
                        } else {
                        builder.setTitle("Availablity");
                        builder.setMessage("Not Available");
                    }
                    }
                    AlertDialog alertDialog=null;

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(fullview.this,"Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog=builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
        });
        request= findViewById(R.id.request);
        request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                request();
            }
        });

    }
    private void request(){


        //String url= "http://192.168.0.136/fyp/bookreq.php";
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(fullview.this);
        Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("http")
                .authority("192.168.0.136")
                .appendPath("fyp")
                .appendPath("bookreq.php")
                .appendQueryParameter("Title",textviewtitle.setText(title););
                Log.i("Info",textviewtitle.setText(title););
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, builder.build().toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.trim().equals("successfull")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Admin For Approval",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(fullview.this,Search.class);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Requested",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error:" +error.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }

    }
```

> 06-25 08:35:33.436 2682-2682/com.desktop.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>
> 06-25 08:35:35.449 2682-2737/com.desktop.app I/Info: title

This is the info show value title instead of correct value

> 06-25 08:35:30.507 2682-2682/com.desktop.app I/Info:     {"ss":true,"search":[{"isbn":195472462,"title":"Oxford Practice Grammer","authors":"john Eastwood","accession":1,"publisher":"Ameena Saiyid Oxford University","pubyear":2014,"pages":432,"rak":1,"hr":1,"vr":1,"barcode":195472462,"status":"yes"},{"isbn":9694946719,"title":"High School English Grammer ","authors":"Wren, martin","accession":4,"publisher":"Paramount Publishing","pubyear":2010,"pages":418,"rak":1,"hr":1,"vr":4,"barcode":9694946719,"status":"yes"}]}
>   06-25 08:35:30.585 2682-2682/com.desktop.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>       finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Here is the correct title I get in above info

Comment: Test case : `.appendQueryParameter("Title",textviewtitle.getText().toString().trim());`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                      at com.desktop.app.fullview.request(fullview.java:146)
@VishvaDave

Comment: May be in copy paste you have done something worng.. as in your code you are able to set text of that textview and if you can set text then can get text also..otherewise there should be npe in that also

Comment: TextView textviewtitle = findViewById(R.id.textviewtitle); 
i use this instead of 
textviewtitle = findViewById(R.id.textviewtitle);

Comment: Make sure this id is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

At first, Make sure you set **PROPER ID**.

```
TextView textviewtitle; // Global


@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullview);

        textviewtitle = findViewById(R.id.textviewtitle); // Check this id
```

**NOTE**

> appendQueryParameter (String key, 
>                   String value)

You should set

```
.appendQueryParameter("Title",textviewtitle.getText().toString());
```

Comment: @AsadMallick You are getting `NullPointerException`. Read my answer once more.

Comment: @AsadMallick if your id is incorrect then how you getting value in info log? and not NPE at that time???

Comment: thanks... how i pass multiple values as title , author , publisher @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: thanks... how i pass multiple values as title , author , publisher @VishvaDave

Comment: @AsadMallick No idea for multiple case. You can ask new question for that. AFAIK no other way.